# break a collection up into smaller collections, but repeat items

Tags: c#, linq

I can't get my head around how to do this.

I have a collection of objects

```
{ object1, object2, object3, object4 }
```

I want to break up this collection into a collection of collections, so that I end up with something that looks like

```
{ { object1, object2}, {object2, object3}, {object3, object4} }
```

I've found how to chunk the collection into smaller ones, but it is the repeating of the previous item in each collection that is doing my head in.

Any help greatly appreciated!

My current chunk method (taken from another question on here) is

```
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Chunk<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int size)
    {
            return source.Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })
                        .GroupBy(x => x.Index / size)
                        .Select(x => x.Select(v => v.Value));
    }
```

**EDIT**
This works, but is there a better way?

```
    public static ICollection<ICollection<T>> BreakUp<T>(this IEnumerable<T> polylines, int size)
    {
        var results = new Collection<ICollection<T>>();
        results.Add(new Collection<T>());

        var x = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < polylines.Count(); i++)
        {
            results[x].Add(polylines.ElementAt(i));

            if (results[x].Count() % size == 0 && i != polylines.Count() - 1)
            {
                x++;
                results.Add(new Collection<T>());
                results[x].Add(polylines.ElementAt(i));
            }
        }

        return results;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure that you can do it in a single lazy lambda expression (like the one you're providing), since you have to return objects twice, LINQ is not really suited for that I think.

Comment: @Maarten Linq is not a requirement, can be loop or anything required

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simplify your code like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> BreakUp<T>(IEnumerable<T> this source, int size)
{
    var max = source.Count();
    int i = 0;
    while (i < max)
    {
        var current = source.Skip(i).Take(size);
        if (current.Count() > 1)
            yield return current;
        i += size -1;
    }
}
```

---

**Test:**

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Example 1");
    var source = new Int32[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    foreach (var i in BreakUp(source, 2))
        Console.WriteLine(i);

    Console.WriteLine("Example 2");

    foreach (var i in BreakUp(source, 4))
        Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

---

Here's a solution that iterates `source` only once:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> BreakUp<T>(IEnumerable<T> this source, int size)
{
    using(var e = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        T last = default(T);
        bool has_last = false;
        while(e.MoveNext())
        {
            var current = new List<T>(size);
            if(has_last)
                current.Add(last);

            last = (T)e.Current;
            current.Add(last);

            while(current.Count < size && e.MoveNext())
            {
                last = (T)e.Current;
                current.Add(last);
                has_last = true;
            }

            yield return current;
        }
    }
}
```

**Results:**

[image]

Comment: as commented above, the number of objects in each collection needs to be variable, would this work?

Comment: So given a collection {`1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`}, do you except {`1`, `2`, `3`}, {`3`, `4`, `5`} or {`1`, `2`, `3`}, {`2`, `3`, `4`}, {`3`, `4`, `5`}?

Comment: given any sized collection, I want to be able to specify a specific number of elements to put into separate sub collections.

Given {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} and size variable of 2 I'd expect

{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}

or given {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} and size variable 4 I'd expect

{1, 2, 3, 4}, {4, 5}

Does that make sense?

Comment: @QldRobbo Using a extension method of clarity is good. I just reworked your code a little bit to make it simpler and lazy.

Comment: @QldRobbo I edited my code to reflect the examples you have given.

Comment: +1. though you really don't need the `current.Count() > 1` check, do you?

Comment: @ErenErsönmez Yes, otherwise the result of the first example would be `{1,2} {2,3} {3,4} {4,5} {5}` instead of `{1,2} {2,3} {3,4} {4,5}`

Comment: great! this passes my unit tests and appears to work perfectly in place of my ugly extension method in the original post.

Thanks for your help @BigYellowCactus

Comment: Nice solution!  I see a couple small improvements you could make, though.  You can avoid having to check `current`'s count by changing `while (i < max)` to `while (i < max - 1)`.  You can also save a couple of lines of code by making the while loop a for loop.  Also, one small issue with this solution is it will iterate through `source` multiple times, when it's possible to iterate once.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to group like this

{ { object1, object2}, {object2, object3}, {object3, object4} }

then following code would suffice

```
return source.Zip(source.Skip(1), (o1, o2) => new List<T> { o1, o2 });
```

EDIT:

Solution for a variable number of elements:

{ { object1, object2, object3}, {object2, object3, object4}, {object3, object4, object5} }

```
source.TakeWhile((o,i) => i <= source.Count() - size)
      .Select((o,i) => source.Where((lo,li) => li >= i && li < i + size));
```

Comment: the number of objects in each collection needs to be variable, would this work?

Comment: For variable number of elements unfortunately not.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, my fault for not being more clear in the question

Comment: This does not give the correct results. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753567/break-a-collection-up-into-smaller-collections-but-repeat-items/11753923#comment15604330_11753923)

Comment: @BigYellowCactus Yes, you are correct, I didn't see the required output.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be as concise as other solutions, but it iterates through `source` only once.

```
public static IEnumerable<List<T>> BreakUp<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int size)
{
    var max = source.Count();
    int start = 0;
    var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
    enumerator.MoveNext();
    // We use "max - 1" instead of "max" to avoid adding a list of length 1
    while (start < max - 1)
    {
        int current = 0;
        List<T> list = new List<T>();
        list.Add(enumerator.Current);
        current++;

        while(current < size && enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            list.Add(enumerator.Current);
            current++;
        }
        yield return list;
        start += size - 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: This also passes my unit tests (but I haven't looked at the actual output yet) so I assume it is also a good solution.

You are also correct in that the while condition can be max - 1 and then the Count() - 1 check in @BigYellowCactus solution is not required